# Create Channel from Socket in grpc-java

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm using grpc in my project, the client side is written in Java and the server side is written in C++.

My question is, in the client side, is there a way to create the `ManagedChannel` from an existing `Socket` object instead of calling `ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.
See also: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/3132

Comment: That link is also my question ;) .